# PaperOnboarding error with OnboardingItemInfo

Tags: ios, swift

I'm following along with this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G5UkS4Mrepo. I have copied the code exactly as shown in the video. Around 15:16 he successfully builds the application, however, I get this error:

> Cannot convert return expression of type '(String, String, String, String, UIColor, UIColor, UIColor, UIFont, UIFont)' to return type 'OnboardingItemInfo'

I know others have asked this question in the past, but in their error message, they have something follwing 'OnboardingItemInfo" while mine just ends there.

This is my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var onboardingView: OnboardingView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    onboardingView.dataSource = self;
}

func onboardingItemsCount() -> Int {
    return 1
}

func onboardingItemAtIndex(_ index: Int) -> OnboardingItemInfo {
    let backgroundColorOne = UIColor(red: 217/255, green: 72/255, blue: 89/255, alpha: 1)
    let backgroundColorTwo = UIColor(red: 106/255, green: 166/255, blue: 211/255, alpha: 1)
    let backgroundColorThree = UIColor(red: 168/255, green: 200/255, blue: 78/255, alpha: 1)

    let titleFont = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Bold", size: 24)!
    let descriptionFont = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 18)!

    return [("rocket", "A Great Rocket Start", "lorem ipsum", "", backgroundColorOne, UIColor.white, UIColor.white, titleFont, descriptionFont)][index]
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your function `onboardingItemAtIndex` is suppose to return what seems to be an instance of the class `OboardingView`, but instead it returns a tuple of values in a _questionable_ way.

Answer (score 0):

The following function `func onboardingItemAtIndex(_ index: Int) -> OnboardingItemInfo` should return some object of type OnboardingItemInfo which can be a struct or class. **However you are doing something totally different** that is `return [("rocket", "A Great Rocket Start", "lorem ipsum", "", backgroundColorOne, UIColor.white, UIColor.white, titleFont, descriptionFont)][index]`

You need to find where the `OnboardingItemInfo` has been defined, and look at its initializers (so you can know how to properly construct and return the object/item).

```
struct StudentInfo { 
  let name: String 
  let age : Int
   // by default the struct gives us a free initializer, so no need to declare one 
}

func something(name: String, age: Int) -> StudentInfo { 
   /*
      here our something function takes a name and age as params 
      and it returns a StudentInfo 
   */
    return StudentInfo(name: name, age: age) //< here we are constructing a StudentInfo with the name and age provided
}
```

Answer (score 0):

return [("rocket", "A Great Rocket Start", "lorem ipsum", "", backgroundColorOne, UIColor.white, UIColor.white, titleFont, descriptionFont)][index]
}

instead of "string", "string" etc

return [(rocket, "A Great Rocket Start", "lorem ipsum", "", backgroundColorOne, UIColor.white, UIColor.white, titleFont, descriptionFont)][index]
}

it is supposed to be a UIImage.

hope that helps!